# Find function in xml

Tags: jquery, xml

How to implement multiple filter condition inside find function in jQuery when parsing xml file? I need something like following:-

```js
var result = $(xml).find("segment[id=1]").find("segment[name=Ron]").text();
```

xml node is like follwing:

```
<segment id="1" name="Ron">PRon.txt</segment>
<segment id="1" name="Jack">Jack.txt</segment>
```

Comment: Without seeing your XML this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, question updated

Comment: Take a look ate the [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one find, and you can join the attributes together like this:

```
var result = $(xml).find("segment[id=1][name=Ron]").text();
```

However it's worth noting that a better XML format to remove the duplicate `id` attributes on those nodes would be something like this:

```
<group id="1">
    <segment name="Ron">PRon.txt</segment>
    <segment name="Jack">Jack.txt</segment>
</group>
```

Which you could then access with:

```
var result = $(xml).find('#1').find('[name="Ron"]').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = $(xml).find('segment[id="1"][name="Ron"]').text();
```